# Copying Angular project directory does not work

Tags: node.js, angular, file-copying

Using Angular [quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html) script is as follows:

```
git clone https://github.com/angular/quickstart.git quickstart
cd quickstart
npm install
npm start
```

When I do this, everything works fine. However, if I copy this directory to create a new Angular project:

```
cp -r quickstart angular-project
cd angular-project
npm install
npm start
```

an error occurs:

```
module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../lib/tsc.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/username/src/angular/quickstart-test1/node_modules/.bin/tsc:2:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
```

even though `tsc.js` exists under `lib/` in new directory.

Why does this error occur?

Answer (score 4):

This is how you'd get around this issue.

if you named your copy of the quickstart project angular-project;

1. Go to that new project folder
   $> cd angular-project
2. Delete node_modules folder inside angular-project
   $> rm -rf node_modules
3. Reinstall
   $> npm install
4. Start your application
   $> npm start

Comment: @Roman C. You actually are in the correct direction. The only missing step for you is deleting the node_modules folder. So your steps would be like this.                                                                                                                         1. cp -r quickstart angular-project  
2. cd angular-project                                                                                                                         
3. rm -rf node_modules   
4. npm install  
5. npm start

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is that the file .angular-cli.json was not copied by "cp" command to your new directory. Add it manually and change the project name inside of it.

Comment: No, `cp -r` copies "hidden files" too. Just tested it.